# Do you need to knockout the hero in CoC to get 100%?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If the hero moves away from the altar, and you destroy it...and the hero doesn't get knocked out the whole battle, can you still get 100%? (even though the chances are 1 in 10000)

Answer (score 1):

Other than the Grand Warden, you do not have to defeat enemy heroes.

You obtain one star for destroying 50% of enemy buildings.

You obtain a second star for destroying the enemy town hall.

You can obtain a third star by destroying all enemy buildings.

Walls and Traps do not count as buildings. Hero *Alters* do count as buildings. And of course the Grand Warden is included as previously mentioned.

In practical terms, you're not often going to be able to destroy all the buildings without first taking down the Heroes, but they are not required.

[Source](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Raids)

Comment: I know the Grand Warden has to be broken during defense cuz he turns into a statue during a defense. But guess the BK is on one corner, and you destroy the altar with a lightning spell, then the BK basically stays unharmed even if the base gets 3-Starred. I guess it's basically like Balloon CC Troops vs Hog Riders.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a CoC pro or anything, but with my experience with the game, you need to knock out the hero(s) to get 100%

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).